# One source form for all the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to figure out how to use the same form in every page without having to paste the same code at every page.
So when the button on click the form will pop out , on submit the form will submit and save to db.
If click close the form will close.

Appreciate an answer to use the same form in every page so that when i edit the form i don't need to go every page to edit the source.

Thank You

Comment: This should be done on the server-side. What you use will depend on your server language. Could be includes, could be templates, could be master pages, could be...

Comment: Are you using a server side language..? have you tried a google search..?

Comment: @Timmah there's no `php` tag in question -__-

Comment: why not something like $( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );?

Comment: So php is recommended to load the form to every page ? what if i don't want my extension as .php ?

Comment: mostly due to the fact that he then asks to input data to a DB ... going to have have to have something server side I'd think.

Comment: ...bah sometime I really dont understand you :)

Comment: the main objective here is i don't want to copy the code for the form in every page. so is there any way i can somehow on click and the form popup (but load from the form page) ?

Comment: yes make an html page with only the form, then load it into each page using the jquery load() function.. what @Infer-On said.

Comment: @webkit but how do i make it popup ? :)

Comment: You load the form.html file into a containing div (your popup) that has a unique ID and is hidden, after the load is successful, you show that containing div with javascript.. use css to position/style the pop up div the way you want

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a modal box to display the form ? Coz if you are using lightbox, you can link the page with the form to the modal without any hassel. And the extra code it will add is pretty much a function to call the box.

If that doesnt work for you , you can switch to an ajax request to get the form and then link to an id.

Otherwise, go for a server side inclusion of the form page.